Issues with Day Off Calculations in Odoo 16
I'm encountering a problem in Odoo 16 related to the calculation of days off in the HR module. Specifically, the days off for an employee are being deducted before the leave request is approved. However, once the request is approved, the remaining days off revert to their original values.
the initial state
The days off decreases immediately after the request is submitted, even though it hasn't been approved yet by the admin
and here the days return to the inital state after the admin approved
